# C fgets function not working when ran on linux

Tags: c

So the problem I'm having is that I believe fgets is getting skipped over but I'm not sure. The code I'm working with looks like this:

```
void createAccount()
{
ignore = fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
printf("Creating A New Account:\n");
FILE *input;
input = fopen("accounts.txt", "a");
if (input == NULL)
{
    printf("Error opening accounts.txt file!\n");
    exit(1);
}
char username[USERNAME_LENGTH];
char password[PASSWORD_LENGTH];
char type[CHOICE_LENGTH];
char age[10];
printf("Username:");
a = fgets(username,USERNAME_LENGTH,stdin);
char *fileOpener = malloc(strlen(username));
if (fileOpener!=NULL) {
    strcpy(fileOpener, username);
}
const size_t end = strlen(fileOpener) - 1;
if (fileOpener[end] == '\n')
    fileOpener[end] = '\0';
ignore = fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
printf("age:");
a = fgets(age,10,stdin);
ignore = fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
printf("Password:");
a = fgets(password,PASSWORD_LENGTH,stdin);
ignore = fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
printf("Account Type:");
a = fgets(type,CHOICE_LENGTH,stdin);
ignore = fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
ignore = fputs(username,input);
ignore = fputs(password,input);
ignore = fputs(type,input);
fclose(input);
FILE *newFile = fopen(fileOpener,"ab+");
char *newAge = malloc(strlen("AGE: " + strlen(age)));
if (newAge!=NULL) {
    strcpy(newAge,"AGE: ");
    strcat(newAge,age);
}
char *newName =malloc(strlen("NAME: " + strlen(username)));
if (newName!=NULL) {
    strcpy(newName,"NAME: ");
    strcat(newName,username);
}
ignore = fputs(newName,newFile);
ignore = fputs(newAge,newFile);
ignore = fputs("MEDICATIONS: ",newFile);
ignore = fputs("\nVITALS: ",newFile);
ignore = fputs("\nHISTORY: ",newFile);
ignore = fputs("\nALLERGIES: ",newFile);
fclose(newFile);
printf("Account made.");
}
```

It scans user input and puts it inside a file. The problem is that it never prompts for the user name, and instead prompts straight for the age, that output looks like this:

```
Creating A New Account:
Username:age:(user input)
Password: (user input)
Account Type: (user input)
```

when it should look like this:

```
Creating A New Account:
Username:(user input)
age:(user input)
Password:(user input)
Account Type:(user input)
```

so it looks like the fgets for the username is just being ignored? And it just goes straight to age, printing it on the same line. This code works fine when I run it on a mac, but I only have this problem on linux. Please help.

Comment: maybe flush your output after the printfs. And also, careful _all_ your string allocations are too short by 1 (nul terminator).

Comment: also `ignore = fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);` looks like a stdin flush to me, undefined behaviour, you don't need it with `fgets`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre fflush(stdout)?

Comment: General rule of thumb: allocate a big buffer (I mean 4096 bytes, maybe only 1024 if you're pressed for space) to read lines into — or use POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) to read lines — and then extract information from that.  This avoids most line-wrapping problems (if the data comes in exceeding the buffer length, your program is probably under attack).  You can use `line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';` to zap the newline.  There are multiple ways to detect whether you got a newline at all (`strcspn()`, `strchr()`, …).

Answer (score -1):

```
void createAccount()
{
fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
printf("Creating A New Account:\n");
FILE *input = fopen("accounts.txt", "a");
if (input == NULL)
{
    printf("Error opening accounts.txt file!\n");
    exit(1);
}
char username[USERNAME_LENGTH];
char password[PASSWORD_LENGTH];
char type[CHOICE_LENGTH];
char age[10];
printf("Username:");
fgets(username,USERNAME_LENGTH,stdin);
char *fileOpener = malloc(strlen(username));
 if (fileOpener == NULL)
{
    printf("cannot allocating the space in malloc!\n");
    exit(1);
}
    strcpy(fileOpener, username);
const size_t end = strlen(fileOpener) - 1;
if (fileOpener[end] == '\n')
    fileOpener[end] = '\0';
fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
printf("age:");
fgets(age,10,stdin);
fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
printf("Password:");
fgets(password,PASSWORD_LENGTH,stdin);
fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
printf("Account Type:");
fgets(type,CHOICE_LENGTH,stdin);
fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
fputs(username,input);
fputs(password,input);
fputs(type,input);
fclose(input);
FILE *newFile = fopen(fileOpener,"ab+");
char *newAge = malloc(strlen("AGE: ") + strlen(age));
if (newAge == NULL) {
   printf("cannot allocating the space in malloc!\n");
    exit(1);
}
 strcpy(newAge,"AGE: ");
    strcat(newAge,age);
char *newName =malloc(strlen("NAME: ") + strlen(username));
if (newName == NULL) {
   printf("cannot allocating the space in malloc!\n");
    exit(1);
}
strcpy(newName,"NAME: ");
    strcat(newName,username);
fputs(newName,newFile);
fputs(newAge,newFile);
fputs("MEDICATIONS: ",newFile);
fputs("\nVITALS: ",newFile);
fputs("\nHISTORY: ",newFile);
fputs("\nALLERGIES: ",newFile);
fclose(newFile);
printf("Account made.");
}
```

you had some problems in your code.

**1:** you don't need to write `a =` or `ignore =` if you don't realy use them.

**2:** change `malloc(strlen("things" + strlen(things)))` to `malloc(strlen("things: ") + strlen(things))

check fore more...

Comment: Should't it be  `malloc(strlen("things: ") + strlen(things) + 1)` (+1) ?

Comment: that doesn't answer the question or really fixes _anything_ mentioned in the comments.. The main issue is probably the first `ignore = fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);`, and there are others like the +1 things on the malloc.